# Create another button when certain input is empty

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, authentication

I am trying to make a login form for a username and a password, but I want it to work like this: when the user clicks the login button while at least one the input fields in empty the login button has to shrink(to the left) to 50% of its original width and another button has to appear to the right of it(equal in size to the other button). The second button says Register.

```
<div class="login">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="user"><br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Login">
       (<input type="button" value="Register"> this is what has to appear)
</div>
```

Comment: attributes can be animated using javaScript or jQuery... I can't think of a way to do this with just HTML/CSS

Comment: Ugh. I just spent twenty minutes coming up with a (pretty neat) solution using jQuery and...no [tag:jquery] tag? I have no idea how I missed that. Still, deleted the answer since it's irrelevant. Sadly...

Answer (score 1):

Make 3 classes for Your buttons in CSS : 1 for a large button, one for half sized button and one for hidden button. give your login the large button class in HTML and your registerbutton the hidden class. Then give your buttons id's as well. When the button is clicked you can check the values of the text box and compare them to an empty string ("") then you can change the classes of the buttons to the half sized button class. More info and code samples about JavaScript and css on w3schools.com

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
<div class="login">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="user">
    <br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Login" id="login" style="width:150">   
    <input type="button" value="Register" hidden="true" id="register">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    login = document.getElementById('login');
    login.addEventListener("click",hide,false);

    function hide()
    {
        user = document.getElementById('user');
        password = document.getElementById('password');
        if(!user.value || !password.value)
        {
            register = document.getElementById('register');
            register.hidden=false;
            current_width = parseInt(login.style.width);
            login.style.width = current_width/2+'px';
            register.style.width = current_width/2+'px';
        }
    }
</script>
```